# Unable to remove directory connected to Netflix

Tags: netflix

Just got a quick question. I am trying to get Netflix to run on Ubuntu since the Silverlight incident in April.
I have of course attempted the solution of removing the directory with:
`rm -Rf ~/.wine-browser` 
However when I attempt to do this I receive the error message that what I'm trying to delete can't be found.
I would really appreciate any advice to get this up and running. 
Would maybe uninstalling and reinstalling Netflix work?

Comment: What is "the Silverlight incident" exactly? If `rm` says the path cannot be found, then it doesn't exist.

Comment: The version of Netflix running on Linux required an update of Silverlight to keep working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use commands for this if you don't want to. It's just a hidden directory in your home folder. In order to view hidden files and folders, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>. Select the folder and delete it as you would with any other file. Then use the previous combination to hide them again. You can also view or hide hidden files using the menu.

If the folder isn't there, then you can't delete it. Sounds like you've already deleted it.